# Find the line number where a specific word appears with "grep"

Tags: unix, sed, grep

Is `grep` capable of providing the line number on which the specified word appears?

Also, is possible to use `grep` to search for a word starting from some certain line downward?

Comment: I believe this would be a better fit for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @dunsmoreb I disagree.  `grep` is as much a programmer's tool as a power users tool.

Comment: I use `grep` all the time.  But this really isn't a programming-related question.

Comment: well I found this question helpful whilst writing a bash script that uses grep

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use `grep -n` to get the line number of a match.

I don't think there's a way to get grep to start on a certain line number.  For that, use sed.  For example, to start at line 10 and print the line number and line for matching lines, use:

```
sed -n '10,$ { /regex/ { =; p; } }' file
```

---

To get only the line numbers, you could use

```
grep -n 'regex' | sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\):.*$/\1/'
```

Or you could simply use sed:

```
sed -n '/regex/=' file
```

Combining the two sed commands, you get:

```
sed -n '10,$ { /regex/= }' file
```

Comment: Ok, so grep -n would return the line that contains the words AND the line number. Is there anyway to get the line number ONLY ?

Comment: @OneTwoThree Did that work for you?

Comment: Tiny correction, missing semi-colon in last example: `sed -n '10,$ { /regex/=;}' file` but otherwise thanks very much, found this useful.

Comment: Does this return only the first match? As in , if there are multiple words matching the regex, then?

Comment: To get only the `grep -n` line number, it's easier with `cut` : `grep -n text file | cut -d":" -f1`

Answer (score 3):

You can call `tail +[line number] [file]` and pipe it to `grep -n` which shows the line number:

```
tail +[line number] [file] | grep -n /regex/
```

The only problem with this method is the line numbers reported by `grep -n` will be `[line number] - 1` less than the actual line number in `[file]`.

Answer (score 2):

Or You can use

```
   grep -n . file1 |tail -LineNumberToStartWith|grep regEx
```

This will take care of numbering the lines in the file

```
   grep -n . file1
```

This will print the last-LineNumberToStartWith

```
   tail -LineNumberToStartWith
```

And finally it will grep your desired lines(which will include line number as in orignal file)

```
grep regEX
```