# Multiple line search in a file using java or unix command

Tags: java, shell, unix, command

I want to find the following pattern in a file like

```
subclass "Pool1" 11:22:33:44:55:66    {

      dynamic;

}
```

the above pattern I have to find in a file.

How can I find either using java or Unix command?

Comment: What part do you want to parse? How do you need the result?

Comment: the pattern I have mentioned subclass "Pool1" 11:22:33:44:55:66 {    dynamic } in dhcpd.leases file

Comment: maybe this can help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589929/find-the-line-number-where-a-specific-word-appears-with-grep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find like this.

```
    File file = new File("data/pattern.txt");
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("subclass \"Pool1\" 11:22:33:44:55:66 \\{\\s*dynamic;\\s*\\}");
    String content = Files.lines(file.toPath()).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(content);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.printf("found at %d-%d%n", m.start(), m.end());
    }
```