# Getting a line number of a specific word from a text file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal, grep

---

My query is:
***I want my bash script to scan a text file for a specific word and store the line number in a variable. I tried using "grep" and "find", but no progress was made.
Is this possible to do?***

---

Comment: Did you forget to insert your code which isn’t working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589929/find-the-line-number-where-a-specific-word-appears-with-grep I found this by googling "grep line number"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. @zzxyz . Your answer is the best on stackoverflow.

Comment: @potato thanks for the lovely response. All thanks to your decent answer, my code is working.

Comment: Weirdo, glad your code is now working.  In light of your statement that @zzxyz's link worked for you, I have marked this question as a duplicate.